# Embedding and executing javafx application on web browser

Tags: javafx-2

I have developed JavaFx application,i wanted to run it in browser but i am not getting executing  it in browser instead i am getting executing it out of browser.I want to execute it within the browser for that i have code.html,w.jnlp,and executable jar.

On directly clicking either on jnlp or on executable jar ,it would work fine but my requirement is ,that application to be embedded into web browser and execute like web application.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question?